# How to Add Some Actions to My Netbeans Project on Build?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7

Is it possible to change on build action of my Netbeans project? If so, how?

For example I have in my project some XML file. I want the file to be found, read, and another file created accordingly when build action is called.

Thanks.

Comment: If you are using ant, you can configure the build.xml file and use ant actions to read / create files.

Comment: is it also possible to run a program from ant ?

Comment: Yes, with the [exec task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html).

Comment: thank you :) that might work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can edit **build.xml** file. There is some examples on how to create new targets for your build script.